# PyQt - QFileDialog selects with single click

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qfiledialog

I have this very strange problem. I use `QFileDialog` to select files, but the selection is done with a **single click**, instead of double click as in everywhere else. Maybe something specific for the *look-and-feel*, or something in the configuration.

My form (single click):

[image]

Eclipse form (double click):

[image]

Any idea how to set it to double-click? Thanks.

Comment: show us your code!

Comment: This behaviour is controlled by your desktop environment. There is no way to change it via qt. The settings are probably picked up from the kdeglobals config file. You need to edit it and set `[KDE] -> SingleClick=false`.

Comment: @ekhumoro Yes that makes total sense. I just realized that running the same app on a different server gives a different form look and a double-click behavior.

Answer (score 1):

This is controlled by the QT5 configuration on your system.
Run qt5ct (on a Unix-like system, or the equivalent elsewhere) and uncheck 'Activate on single click'.

[image: QT5 configuration]